# Want to delete the excel data after saving the data into database in Django

Tags: django-views

Want to delete the excel data after saving the data into database in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the excel file, you can `import os` and use the `os.remove` method to delete a file.

Since the variable `path` appears to contain the file path to your csv file, all you need to do to delete the file is to use `os.remove(path)`.

Alternatively, to clear the contents of the csv file instead, you can open the file for writing and close it immediately.

```
open(path, "w").close()
```